# Cron expression isn't working as intended for spring boot

Tags: spring, cron, cron-task, spring-scheduled

I wan't to have a method run every sunday at 1:30 PM so far I can get thing to run like every 10 minutes or at 1:30 every day, but now specific day

Here is what I have so far

```
 /**
     * Fires at 1:30 PM sundauy
     */
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 30 13 * 1 ?")
    fun sendNotifications() {

    }
```

I think the problem is in the day of month field possibly? or sunday isn't 1 indexed. I see in other con implementations its 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the 5th field is used for "month" while 6th field is for "day of week" (see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html#cron--) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html)), so your expression (`"0 30 13 * 1 ?"`) will fire your method at "13:30 of every day in January".

weekday names can be given as the first three letters of the English names. in order to schedule a method to run "every sunday at 13:30" this expression can be used:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 30 13 ? * SUN")
```